# Magento Attributes search filter not correct

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have problem with my Magento Attributes search filter not correct. For example this page

http://www.siameyewear.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=Ray-Ban

As you can see. I have all the list created with magento attibutes at the left side bar. 
All list have show correct as i want. But when i'm click on it such as WAYFARER ® (1) <<< There are only 1 product on a list. But it's look like magento show all my products. Normally it have have to show only 1 product as they say.

Second question. 
I have set Is Anchor to yes in Category. 
For example this page. http://www.siameyewear.com/rayban.html
As you can see Magento show Anchor correctly. ( below "Shop By")
But when I'm click on it. All the page getting error 404 page can't be found.

Anyone know how to fix this problem. Kindly Please help. I'm stuck with this problem for a weeks. 
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

For Search Filter you should delete all files under var/locks and then reindex all.